LOF page numbers for front and back cover
I use \includepdf to add a front and back cover to a document. Those pages use images I want to add to the LOF.
\addcontentsline{lof}{figure}{Front Cover}
\addcontentsline{lof}{figure}{Back Cover}

This works fine, but the page number is wrong. How can I manually overwrite or omit it for these two entries?

Add the line on the page. You provided no code so it isn't possible to show you how to adapt what you have, but you basically want something like the following:
\includepdf[pagecommand={\addcontentsline{lof}{figure}{Cover art}\pagestyle{empty}}]{example-image-a4}
\includepdf[pagecommand={\addcontentsline{lof}{figure}{Back cover art}\pagestyle{empty}}]{example-image-a4}

MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pagecommand={\addcontentsline{lof}{figure}{Cover art}\pagestyle{empty}}]{example-image-a4}
\title{title}
\author{awdur}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\section{a}
abc    
\end{document}


\includepdf[addtolist={1,figure,Cover page,fig:cover}]{example-image-a4} is generally better, then links from the list of figures works correctly (on the first page it doesn't matter but on other pages they would be wrong with your method unless you also add an anchor).

@UlrikeFischer oh, you mean the back cover will be wrong?
